# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python, string

i'm new to coding part this is the first code i want to try

```py
dob = int(input('please enter your date of birth: '))
print(dob)
cy = 2020
age= cy-dob
print (age)
if age == '>=1' | '<=12':
    print('You are a child')
elif age == '>=13' | '<=19':
    print('You are a teen')
elif age == '>=20' | '<=40':
    print('You are an adult')
else:
    print('You are a elder')
```

but when I run it displays:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: If youre trying to use the or operator, in python use `or`.   Why is your code in a string? how would `age` ever equal `'>=1'`?

Comment: You are thinking JavaScript. In python it is `or`

Answer (score 1):

Python's operands and expression don't work this way. (article about them [realpython.com](https://realpython.com/python-operators-expressions/#:%7E:text=An%20operand%20can%20be%20either,combining%20data%20objects%20into%20expressions.))

You used [`bitwise`](https://realpython.com/python-operators-expressions/#bitwise-operators) operators for string comparison. If you tried to run an `OR` expression
the appropriate python example for strings would be. (oriented aroumd your code)

```py
if foo == "<=" or foo == ">=":
    print(1)
```

This operation could also be represented as:

```py
if foo in ["<=", ">="]:
    print(1)  # will be printed if foo <= or >=
```

For `AND` operations you can use the same syntax with `and`:

```py
if foo >= 20 and foo <= 40:
    print(1)  # will b printed if 40 > foo  > 20
```

You also will encounter a syntax error in your current code due to a space between `print` and `(age)`

Fixed Version of your script:

```py
dob = int(input('please enter your date of birth: '))
print(dob)
cy = 2020
age= cy-dob
print(age)
if age >=1 and age <=12:
   print('You are a child')
elif age >= 13 and age <= 19:
    print('You are a teen')
elif age >=20 and age <=40:
    print('You are an adult')
else:
    print('You are an elder')
```

Answer (score 0):

Rikden Gurung
Try using 'or' operator instead of '|'.

```
dob = int(input('please enter your date of birth: '))

age= 2020 -dob
#print (age)
if age >=1 or age<=12:
 print('You are a child')
elif age >=13 or age <=19:
 print('You are a teen')
elif age >=20 or age <=40':
 print('You are an adult')
else:
 print('You are a elder')`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dob = int(input('please enter your year of birth: '))
print(dob)
cy = 2020
age= cy-dob
print (age)
if age >=1 and age <= 12:
  print('You are a child')
elif age >=13 and age <=19:
  print('You are a teen')
elif age >=20 and age<=40:
  print('You are an adult')
else:
  print('You are a elder')
```

Output:
please enter your year of birth: 1950
1950
70
You are a elder

Hi, So I've made a number of changes to your code. 
In python, you need to use the 'or' operator instead of '|'.But in your case, you actually need an 'and' operator.

Check out this link to learn more about the operators.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-logical-operators-with-examples-improvement-needed/